# In ARCGIS 10.2 can I create a 2 page map document that prints an image on the back side of the page?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, layouts

From arcgis 10.2 I need to create a pdf file that will print a map on the front side of a page and an image on a back side of the page. How would I do this?

Comment: Export two times to pdf and merge the files, then print on both sides?

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with GIS specifically. If you want something on the back of a page, make the document 2 pages long and then print in duplex on your printer. Page 2 will print on the back of page 1.

Comment: Your printer needs to support duplex (double-sided) printing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll likely want to use [ExportToPDF (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/ExportToPDF/00s300000027000000/) to generate your individual PDFs.  Then you can combine the individual PDF's using [PDFDocumentCreate (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/PDFDocumentCreate/00s300000019000000/).

If you need help getting started with scripting, read [Getting started with arcpy.mapping tutorial (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Getting_started_with_arcpy_mapping_tutorial/00s30000006w000000/)

The code sample at the bottom of the page even shows you how to append new pages into your PDF.

Comment: there is also an older help document that shows an example of facing pages (if that is what you are thinking when you say both sides). otherwise your printer settings determine the printing on both sides. Search "facing pages" on resources page.